# How to forward non-www to www. Using Godaddy DNS Manager

Tags: dns, godaddy, domain-forwarding

so I've set `www.mydomain.com` to point to `ghs.google.com`, which correctly loads my Google site, but if you go to `mydomain.com`, it doesn't redirect/forward to `www.mydomain.com`, it just hangs. is there a way to change this in the Godaddy DNS manager?

Comment: I had a goDaddy account and their support is actually nice. Give them a call and they'll help you. Other than that I don't think this is the place for such a question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's not a DNS setting; you need to set up a redirect from `mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.com`.  Fortunately, Godaddy provides this service for free; follow the directions at https://ph.godaddy.com/help/forward-a-domain-12123

Comment: Does this forward `http://example.com/something` to `http://www.example.com/something` or does it ignore the rest of the URL?

Comment: @CodingTales: yes, it will redirect all requests to the same URL with just the hostname replaced.

Comment: I have domain with godaddy called bgrnature.com and when I type bgrnature.com, its not forwarding to the site. I had to add www prefix. How can I use it without type www as prefix?

Comment: @kittu Forward the domain name to www.bgrnature.com

Comment: I think this is a better fit with the original question (forwarding a root domain → www): https://ph.godaddy.com/help/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-or-subdomain-422

Answer (score 0):

Its not subdomain at all. I am using domain forwarding. Just select forward of domain, not subdomain, and add www to it, and forward only, and it automatically adds the ip address in the A record of DNS in godaddy. If you are using cloudflare, do it in the dns settings on godaddy first and then add domain to cloudflare or if you are already using cloudflare, the delete domain off of cloudflare, and redo the dns and forwarding on godaddy, then rescan on cloudflare, if the dns settings do not show up from godaddy, then add them from godaddy by copying and pasting the settings over to cloudflare, and then add cloudflare nameservers over to godaddy.

If you arent using cloudflare, then just forward the domain non www to the forwarding of www under domain forwarding in godaddy as said at first, then wait and it will do it. I put an extra A record with * pointing to the forwarding ip address too, so you have two A records, one with * and other with @ pointing to ip address.