# My webpage works using HTTP, but not using www

Tags: web-development

I'm sorry to repeat this question as I saw it was previously asked. I would just like the answer in something that a complete idiot and newbie web developer (me) can understand.

I actually hired a web developer to make my page for me and it only works when using HTTP and not when using `www`. They told me that everything was correct on their end and to contact the help desk at my domain server (GoDaddy).

Is there something in GoDaddy that I can go check and fix myself to correct the problem?

Comment: This makes no sense at all. http is a protocol and www is a common subdomain name.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects

Comment: GoDaddy uses Apache on there shared hosting packages, you make a htaccess file. If your domain is pointing to their name servers then a htaccess file is enough, if not you need to point A records to www. If this is too tricky then I recommend you ask your web developer to interment these changes. There is hundreds of guides online that you can follow to get this done.

Comment: Its always better to do redirects on the host level. This allows faster edits and as well as more complex redirects.

Comment: Chelsea are you running WordPress or some other CMS on your website? If so it may be the application forcing the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

**Redirect non-www to www using GoDaddy’s Subdomain Forward**

[Source:](http://www.bybe.net/blog/12-easy-steps-on-setting-up-a-non-www-to-www-redirect-using-godaddy.html)

> I have not personally tested this method and as mentioned earlier in
>   this tutortial I recommend you always do redirects on the hosting
>   level for various reasons. In the event that you prefer this method
>   and it doesn’t work let me know.
>
> Step 1: Login to GoDaddy.
>
> Step 2: Click my account.
>
> Step 3: Expand the domains list by clicking the plus sign.
>
> Step 4: Click launch on the domain that you wish to setup the forward.
>
> Step 5: Now find forward and click it… now you want to click again but
>   this time on forward subdomain.
>
> Step 6: Now you should notice that a popup box has appeared, you want
>   to enter the sub domain as www and then type the full address like the
>   example below.

I decided to do a write up on this on my blog but decided not to include the pictures on here since well GoDaddy are often updating their panel and I imagine the pictures will become dated in good time. Editing an answer is easier than having to go back and edit pictures. Anyhow. This question has also be asked on PRO Webmasters before here:  [How to forward non-www to www. Using Godaddy DNS Manager](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9849/how-to-forward-non-www-to-www-using-godaddy-dns-manager) and you can find more information on GoDaddy's site here: [Forwarding or Masking Your Domain Name](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name).

I personally recommend that you do not proceed with a redirect on a DNS level since these changes take longer to take place than that using a htaccess file. You should opt to use a htaccess method which you can find many Q&A here on Pro Webmasters such as [What are the most commonly used and basic Apache htaccess redirects?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects).

Comment: Lot's of DNS providers recommend hosting redirects over their inbuilt DNS management. For example DYN. A server redirecting from A to B using htaccess uses little more than a normal visit since every visit is checked against the HTaccess even when correct URLS are inputted, so this is not entirely correct. All administrators at some point need to do edits to the htaccess and its no reason why to prelong it. Another reason could be is its actually slower having a provider do the redirect as well you don't have control of their system and it is an additional DNS look up on their IP.

Comment: But with this said I believe both methods are equally ok, I disagree with you believing that this is better being done on the DNS level since there is little, to no difference apart from the fact your adding an additionally lookup. If you look at GoDaddy's redirect service within the blog post I posted in source, your see that the system wasn't setup for this since you need to add subdomain and then add the same again.. There is no non-www to www, and if DNS providers believed this was the best method I'm sure they would just have a simple non-www to www within the control panel which few do.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not easy to understand. It would help if you provided an example of what works (i.e. using HTTP) and what does not work (i.e. using `www`).

However, I've noticed that some people believe that *all* web addresses should start with `www`, and become frustrated when they don't.  In other word, they believe that an web-address typed like this:

```
http://example.com
```

also can be typed like this:

```
www.example.com
```

This is not the case.  In the first addrsss, HTTP tells the web browser what protocol to use.  Since HTTP is the default protocol, typing this:

```
example.com
```

will also work.

However `www.example.com` is a different address, and will not necessarely work.

I suspect that this may be your problem.

If that is the case, you need to set up `www.example.com` to be an alias for, or to forward to, `example.com`.  You do this in the DNS control panel at your ISP (GoDaddy).

The simplest thing to do is to set up a `CNAME` record where `www.example.com` points to `example.com` in your DNS configuration.  Ask GoDaddy support for help if you can't figure out how to do this yourself.

In all the examples above, replace `example.com` with your actual domain.